# JWT Token authentication in APIGateway

Tags: jwt, api-gateway

i am working on spring boot application with api gateway and JWT token authentication. after applying the spring security JWT authentication the gateway route functionality not working .i am getting 404 resource not found exception. Please some help me where i am doing wrong.

Comment: Which service are you using to get that JWT token? Is it Cognito?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.